# DynamoDB and .NET Object Persistence Model, using 'ADD' values instead of overwrite

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, object-persistence

I have several DynamoDB tables that will act as aggregate data stores (we are 'rolling up' reports on the fly). I was hoping to use the .NET: Object Persistence Model (where you build classes that have annotations on them). The problem is the DynamoDBContext object only seems to have a 'Save' method and not a 'Save and Add values' method. Because the time between retrieving an object from Dynamo and the time to write to that row again could be larger than a trivial amount, and more than one thread could be attempting to increment, I don't want the increment to be done in the .NET code. Instead I want the .ADD AttributeAction. But I'm not sure if you can specify an attribute action with the Object Persistence Model. Does anyone know if that's possible?

```
[DynamoDBTable("my_table")]
public class MyRecord
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey(AttributeName = "my_id")]
    public string MyID{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hash of the Region and Country fields for unique data lookup from DynamoDB
    /// </summary>
    [DynamoDBRangeKey(AttributeName = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty("my_count")]
    public int MyCount{ get; set; }
```

Above is a sample object. The idea is that MyID gets several 'counts' which represent user actions. I don't want to have to get mycount then add 1 in .NET then re-push. I'd rather run the 'Add' command and always send '1' to mycount and have dynamo do the math to guarantee correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not finding a ton of resources on this, I've decided to write my own extension method for this. It's not perfect in that you can't divine the DBClient object from the context because it's not public, so you have to pass it in.

https://gist.github.com/edgiardina/9815520

However, I'll leave this question unanswered since I don't know if there's an easier way to execute this.